# How to refresh/requery report in access VBA before auto-exporting it on database launch

Tags: email

I searched thoroughly and tried many different solutions, but I can't seem to get it to work, even though it shouldn't be that difficult.

I have an access database which automatically sends reports by e-mail, every monday morning, when the database is opened. The problem is I can't get the reports to show the most recent data in the charts. The procedure is as follows (with Report1 as example)

(Users open a .accdr version of the database)
Upon opening this code runs when the head form loads (form_load event):

```
If Weekday(Now(), 2) = 1 Then   
If Forms![Head Form]![Once subform].Form![ID] = 0 Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateOnce1", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-Report 1"

Dim strSql
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim Outlook
Dim rng
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "number of mail adresses"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Report 1"
.HTMLBody = ""
.Attachments.Add ("T:\.....\Report1.pdf")
.Send

End With


DoCmd.Close acReport, "Report1"

End If
End If
```

So if it is monday, and the code hasn't run yet, Report 1 is openend, exported to PDF, added as an attachment and then mailed via outlook.

As you can see I currently tried opening the reports before calling the code to mail the pdf, in hopes of refreshing it before it exports. But it doesn't seem to be working unfortunately, because the report doesn't show the most recent data.

Any ideas on how I can refresh/requery the report before it is exported & mailed? Much appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is a make table with the most recent data you want when your criteria is met (monday, not been ran yet) and base the report off that, then once you have exported the report delete the temp table with your data. This also prevents users pissing around with your queries/set up etc.

a bit like

```
dim ssql as string

    sSql = "Select yourFields from yourTable INTO tmpTblRpt"
currentdb.execute(ssql)
'set the rpt to be based off tmptblRpt here
then set warnings off docmd.deleteObject actable, "tmpTblRpt" then warnings back on
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot a.s.a.p. and get back to you.